# How to get the API response from a csv file Using Bottle in python

Tags: html, python-3.x, bottle

Below is the sample of the CSV file(sample.csv) i am using

```
ID  Name         Address        Ph.no    Category
1   Person 1    Address 1   1234568789  Category1
2   Person 2    Address 2   1234568790  Category2
3   Person 3    Address 3   1234568791  Category3
4   Person 4    Address 4   1234568792  Category4
5   Person 5    Address 5   1234568793  Category1
6   Person 6    Address 6   1234568794  Category2
7   Person 7    Address 7   1234568795  Category3
8   Person 8    Address 8   1234568796  Category2
9   Person 9    Address 9   1234568797  Category1
```

Using Bottle Framework i want to build a restful webservice to query this CSV file. The Request will be “/getDetails?category=x”.Response should be table of records (tuples) of ID,Name,Address, Ph.no belong to the category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to do it:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, response
from json import dumps
import csv
output = []
# API Endpoint
@get('/getDetails')
def get_details():
    category = request.forms.get('category')
    response.content_type = 'application/json'        
    # read csv file
    csv_file = open("file-question", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    #Traversing the CSV file
    for row in reader:
        if row[4] == category:
            output.append(row)
    # Return Output
    return dumps(output)
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```